# How to customize Edit Text View

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make a Text Editor like a Notepad ...I have created a simple Edit Text View but when I set its height to match_parent it start writing from the center of the screen and above when I add a line.

How should I customize my Edit Text View to make it multiline and view and edit for example a 20-line document?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:gravity="top"
```

to start typing from top in editText